# Determine the number of threads that a method uses

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a method that looks somewhat like this:

```
public void DoLotsOfWork()
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod1());

   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod2());

   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod3());    
}
```

These tasks in turn call other methods, some use `Parallel.Invoke` and some create other `Tasks`. Is there's a way to know how many concurrent threads are running when this method runs?

Comment: not easily unless you observe the thread pool or develop your own scheduler.

Comment: No.  What are you trying to do? Note that `Task` does not use threads directly.

Comment: @SLaks: When this method runs, the production site slows down to a crawl (it's hosted on a shared server, for now). It only lasts 2 minutes and it only runs every 3 hours, but I'm suspecting that the number of threads in use is too high, which is what I'm trying to determine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way I have used in the past is to create an integer variable or property in the parent, and have your SomeMethod1,2 & 3 include a call to Interlocked.Increment(intProperty); at the beginning, and in a finally block call Interlocked.Decrement(intProperty). You can use that property to check how many threads you currently have running.

Your class would look like this:

```
public class MyThreadingClass
{
   int threadCount = 0;
   public void DoLotsOfWork()
   {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod());
   }
   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      Interlocked.Increment(threadCount);
      try
      {
         // Some Code
      }
      finally
      {
         Interlocked.Decrement(threadCount);
      }
   }
}
```